# Wait till audio element fully downloaded. HTML

Tags: html, html5-audio

I searched a lot but didn't find any good solution for this.
I want to load an audio file fully and play after.
`canplay`, and `canplaythrough` event didn't do this.
The browser (chrome latest) didnt load all the audio,just partial content. Chrome sometimes in show in network tab "pending". I develope it in localhost, and i disabled all extension, and i use cache.
Any idea?

```
            var tAudio = document.createElement('audio');
            tAudio.src=src;
            tAudio.preload="auto";
            tAudio.volume=1;
            tAudio.muted=true;
            tAudio.load();
            tAudio.addEventListener('canplaythrough',function() {
                audioLoaded++;
                if (audioLoaded==audioCount){
                    $('.loadingOverlay').fadeOut(1000);    
                }                    
            });
```

Comment: Include your code.

Comment: Here it is. There are more audio element thatwhy you see audioLoaded variable.